# numpy vstack vs. column_stack

Tags: python, numpy

What exactly is the difference between numpy `vstack` and `column_stack`. Reading through the documentation, it looks as if `column_stack` is an implementation of `vstack` for 1D arrays. Is it a more efficient implementation? Otherwise, I cannot find a reason for just having `vstack`.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I think the following code illustrates the difference nicely:

```
>>> np.vstack(([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> np.column_stack(([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
>>> np.hstack(([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

I've included `hstack` for comparison as well.  Notice how `column_stack` stacks along the second dimension whereas `vstack` stacks along the first dimension.  The equivalent to `column_stack` is the following `hstack` command:

```
>>> np.hstack(([[1],[2],[3]],[[4],[5],[6]]))
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

I hope we can agree that `column_stack` is more convenient.

Comment: A simpler equivalent for `column_stack` is `np.vstack(([1,2,3],[4,5,6])).T` which only differs by the transpose, as in @SethMMorton answer.

Answer (score 24):

`hstack` stacks horizontally, `vstack` stacks vertically:

[image]

The problem with `hstack` is that when you append a column you need convert it from 1d-array to a 2d-column first, because 1d array is normally interpreted as a vector-row in 2d context in numpy:

```
a = np.ones(2)          # 2d, shape = (2, 2)
b = np.array([0, 0])    # 1d, shape = (2,)

hstack((a, b)) -> dimensions mismatch error
```

So either `hstack((a, b[:, None]))` or `column_stack((a, b))`:

[image]

where `None` serves as a shortcut for `np.newaxis`.

If you're stacking two vectors, you've got three options:
[image]

As for the (undocumented) `row_stack`, it is just a synonym of `vstack`, as 1d array is ready to serve as a matrix row without extra work.

The case of 3D and above proved to be too huge to fit in the answer, so I've included it in the article called [Numpy Illustrated](https://medium.com/better-programming/numpy-illustrated-the-visual-guide-to-numpy-3b1d4976de1d?source=friends_link&sk=57b908a77aa44075a49293fa1631dd9b).

Answer (score 17):

In the Notes section to [column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html), it points out this:

> This function is equivalent to `np.vstack(tup).T`.

There are many functions in `numpy` that are convenient wrappers of other functions.  For example, the Notes section of [vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) says:

> Equivalent to `np.concatenate(tup, axis=0)` if tup contains arrays that are at least 2-dimensional.

It looks like `column_stack` is just a convenience function for `vstack`.

Comment: It is rather a convenience function for hstack, not for vstack.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins Ah, I see. Numpy has changed their documentation in the 7 years since I posted this answer to say that `column_stack` is more like `hstack` than `vstack`. Interesting. Well, you can always edit this answer to improve it, but I'm guessing based on the downvote you think it should just be deleted?

Comment: The question was: what's the difference between vstack and column_stack. The proper answer would be "the difference is that they stack along different axes". The approved answer does not say it explicitly (which gives some room for improvement), but provides examples, which is good enough. Your answer is that one function is the wrapper of the other, which is not the case. The documentation has changed, but the behaviour didn't (in particular, both of your quotes hold true). I think this answer should be improved. Or deleted, maybe.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins Sounds like you should post a new answer since neither existing ones are satisfactory.

Comment: Yes, that might be a good idea. I like answering questions which are 7 years old :)

Comment: Done. Feel free to downvote me in revenge :)

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins Haha. No, if my answer is no longer relevant than it deserves a downvote.

Comment: I've written a huge article about this (and numpy in general) on medium, thought you might want to have a look: [Numpy Illustrated](https://medium.com/better-programming/numpy-illustrated-the-visual-guide-to-numpy-3b1d4976de1d?source=friends_link&sk=57b908a77aa44075a49293fa1631dd9b)